# Adjust Carousel View for Different Screen Sizes in Xcode for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have set up the following Carousel on my View Controller. I wanted to ask that how can I adjust the Carousel for different screen sizes as I don't have any physical constraints set up in my storyboard.? I have already set up Constraint class for different devices, but How can I link that class with constraints of the Carousel View? Appreciate your help!

```
let myCarousel: iCarousel = {
    let view = iCarousel()
    view.type = .rotary
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.addSubview(myCarousel)
    myCarousel.dataSource = self
    myCarousel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 220, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 400)

    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: set costrains in code to the desired height and width and top constraint equals to 220. with that will be same aspect in different screen sizes

Comment: @kjoe  Yes! Could give me an example on how can I do that in the code? Thanks!

Comment: are you sure height will be across all devices 400 always. Is hardcode size. to make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call view.frame.size.width ondidload, it does not work, it returns stoaryboard size. Actually you want to device width. There are two options.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.addSubview(myCarousel)
    myCarousel.dataSource = self
    myCarousel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 220, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 400)

    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Option 1

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
     myCarousel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 220, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 400)
}
```

Option 2

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(myCarousel)
    myCarousel.dataSource = self
    myCarousel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 220, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 400)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Additional Option:
i did library for carouselview. You can use it.
https://github.com/sonmezvolkan/UIBannerView

Comment: Thanks for the help! I actually want to adjust the height and y - axis for the Carousel View for different devices. How can I add a top constraint for the carousel view? Thanks!

Comment: Then do not use height, use aspect Ratio constraint, actualy you dont need to top constraint for different devices. use leading, trailing and top, and aspect ratio. you will get it you want